# Jackson Deserialization based on array index or key value

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have an API which returns an array of 2 objects. My problem is that each object has a different type. I can deserialize it if its 1 element each but when it returns multiple elements with different types I'm struggling to find out how to do that. An example of the JSON is below. One possible way to deserialize is based on the array index because we can guarantee the order and thus force a type. Another is based on the result of the path key which will always the return the same value for each element.

```
[
  {
    "path": "matter",
    "result": {
      "criticalDates.dateClosed": {
        "id": "-2",
        "name": "Date Closed",
        "confirmed": false,
        "confirmStatus": "Complete",
        "order": 2,
        "status": "Complete",
        "isConfirmable": true,
        "displayName": "Date Closed",
        "autoCalc": false,
        "__id": "e9d-4329-bb4a-03e644afdfda",
        "__className": "CriticalDate",
        "__tableId": "-24",
        "__classes": [
          "CriticalDate"
        ],
        "date": null
      },
      "matterType": "Family",
      "personActing.fullName": "Michael"
    },
    "status": "ok"
  },
  {
    "path": "matter.cardList",
    "result": [
      {
        "person.firstNames": "Daniel Testing",
        "person.lastName": "Lastname"
      },
      {
        "person.firstNames": "Daniel Testing",
        "person.lastName": "Lastname"
      }
    ],
    "status": "ok"
  }
]
```

What would be the appropriate way to deserialize this? Is there an annotation only approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `JsonTypeInfo` to determine the target class.

**Sample DTOs:**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "path")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MatterPath.class, name = "matter"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CardListPath.class, name = "matter.cardList")})
public abstract class AbstractPath {
    private String path;

   // Getters and Setters
}

//------------------------------
public class MatterPath extends AbstractPath {
    private String matterType;
    // Other fields, getter and setters
}
//---------------------------------
public class CardListPath extends AbstractPath{
    private String cardListType;
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. `@JsonTypeInfo` - Use this annotation to determine the subclass based on the existing property. In our case `path`. For further details refer [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html).
2. `@JsonSubTypes` - Use this annotation to map the value in `path` field and the destination class to be used. For details refer [JsonSubTypes](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSubTypes.html).

**Testing:**

```
String json = "[\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"path\": \"matter\",\n" +
        "      \"matterType\": \"Family\"\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"path\": \"matter.cardList\",\n" +
        "    \"cardListType\": \"ok\"\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "]\n";
AbstractPath[] abstractPaths = objectMapper.readValue(json, AbstractPath[].class);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(abstractPaths));
```

**Output:**

```
[MatterPath{matterType='Family'}, CardListPath{cardListType='ok'}]
```